# ASP.NET MVC 5 Cache CSS and JS Files

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5. My goal is to cache CSS and JS files for at least 24 hours. I tried this code with no luck:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache

I added this code, but I still see no caching:

```html
    public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("X-Powered-By");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNet-Version");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNetMvc-Version");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;
            AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;
        }

        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection.Equals(false) && HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal.Equals(false))
                Response.Redirect("https://" + Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"] + HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Set("Cache-Control", "private, max-age=31536000");
        }
    }
```

Result:

GET http://localhost:51000/content/assets/css/colors.min.css HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:51000
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `web.config` file, add

```
<staticContent>
  <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="1:00:00"/>
</staticContent>
```

under `system.webServer` section.

**cacheControlMaxAge** format is **"DAY:HOUR:SECOND"** .

It's working for me. Hopefully it's help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the startup for most modern sites in c#.
The below will add a cache for js, css and fonts.

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            OnPrepareResponse = context =>
            {
                var cachePeriod = "10600";
                if (!context.File.Name.EndsWith(".js") && 
                    !context.File.Name.EndsWith(".css") && 
                    !context.File.Name.EndsWith(".woff")) 
                    return;
                
                context.Context.Response.Headers.Append("Cache-Control", $"public,max-age={cachePeriod}");
            }
        });
```